# Can Sente be used in a server-only configuration?

Tags: clojure, websocket, sente

I'm looking to replace an existing Websocket-based server with a new version written in Clojure. It seems like the **[Sente](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente)** library might be an appropriate choice for this. One thing that isn't clear to me, however, is to what extent Sente relies on a private internal protocol for its operation.

In my case, I have an existing server and client which use JSON-over-websockets, and I'd like to replace the server **without** modifying any client code. It seems like Sente has a lot of specific expectations about the nature of client requests -- for example, it expects clients to specify a `client-id` parameter and to accept `:chsk/handshake` messages from the server.

Is my use case simply outside of the design space that Sente targets? If so, is there a less opinionated implementation of websockets for Clojure that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, I found that Sente is a poor fit for server-only, since it has a lot of implicit assumptions about the protocol it uses. I found that [HTTP-Kit](http://www.http-kit.org/) was more suitable for my use case.